# About the "Permanence" of Angry Predator Frenzy (Martial Arts Charm)

Tags: exalted, exalted-3e

Reading the Angry Predator Frenzy charm (The last one of the Tiger Style charms), it says:

> *Cost: — (+5m, 1wp); Type: Permanent; Duration: Permanent.*

But reading the charm, it clearly says:

> As the martial artist enters the Tiger Form, she may pay an additional five motes and a point of Willpower to unleash the Angry Predator Frenzy, roaring with bestial fury as she casts aside the restraints of humanity.

From what I understand, the "Permanent" part is kind of a lie, because it needs to be activated together with the Tiger Form, each time you want to use it.

However, a player of the game I'm narrating (who wants to buy it) considers that it works permanently. Meaning you only pay the cost once, and you remain in that form for ever.

Which of these is the correct interpretation?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My reading is that it's labelled as *Permanent* because it applies a permanent modification to the Form charm.

That is, the charm itself doesn't have a separate activation, it only changes the form charm to make the extra abilities available if you pay the extra cost when activating that.

So, the effect is tied to the Form charm – scene-long, 10m to activate the base version, 15m, 1wp to activate the enhanced version.

One thing that doesn't seem to be specified is how/whether you can Frenzy while *already* in the Form. It seems thematic to say that you could either upgrade as a Simple action, or reflexively using the same trigger as the Form charm, by paying the upgrade cost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the same. But nonetheless asked to see if anyone understood it in a different way.